# DC to DC converter, different V-

Tags: dc-dc-converter

We currently have a DC to DC converter (12V to 5V), but it seems that the V- of the input and output have a difference of around 1V. However, we need to have a single reference everywhere. Can I safely connect V- of input and output?

It's this one: https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSD-30/RSD-30-SPEC.PDF

Comment: What is the impedance or current when connected with a small R?

Comment: Depends on the converter.  Can you link to the datasheet or at least give a part number?

Comment: "A dc to dc converter"... this is like asking what kind of oil can be used on white cars.

Comment: Did you choose an isolated converter for a reason? Is isolation a requirement? (If it is, that's contradictory to your requirement for a common reference)

Comment: No, we have one from another project and look into reusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which DC-DC converter for stepping down the voltage are you using? The non-isolated such as [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) or the isolated one such as [fly-buck converter](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/passive_components_custom_magnetics/blog_pbcm/blog_detail_electronics_in_action_68928.php)?

If it's an isolated converter then it is normal that there will be a voltage difference whether it is an AC or DC voltage within the negative terminal. It is the result of the [parasitic capacitive coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling#Parasitic_capacitive_coupling) within the transformer.

By using a high input impedance multimeter, you can classify if it's an isolated or not by touching your probe while measuring the voltage between the negative terminal. If the voltage is dropped then it's an isolated converter. Your body will acts as a load and the stray capacitive coupling voltage will be dropped.

Or by using a low input impedance multimeter, the stray capacitance won't affect your measurement, sometimes you need high one, sometimes you need a low one, it depends on your needs, really.

> Certain models of Keysight’s handheld multimeters, for example, the [U1242C](https://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5992-2704EN.pdf), have a unique feature: a ZLow function (Figure 2) that allows you to switch from high input impedance mode to low input impedance mode to check for the presence of stray voltages. This solution eliminates the need to carry both a low impedance meter and a high impedance meter.
>   https://community.keysight.com/community/keysight-blogs/general-electronics-measurement/blog/2018/04/25/how-to-detect-stray-voltages-with-a-handheld-multimeter

[image]

Comment: I believe you have "buck converter" and "fly-buck converter confused with eachother.  The fly-buck is the isolated topology.

Comment: @KH Ups, yes, typo happened sometimes.

Comment: It's this one: https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSD-30/RSD-30-SPEC.PDF. I'll measure it to see which one it is. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Patrik Three clues can be seen that from the datasheet that it is isolated. 4kVDC isolation, galvanically isolated shown in the block diagram, and multiple of it can be operated in series.

Comment: @Patrik  Yes, you can safely connect V- of input and output of an isolated converter. But it's overkill and waste of money. If you have non-isolated one, then use it instead, since the benefit of being an isolated power supply is nullified by shorting the ground.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! We have it from another project and we would like to reuse components.

Answer (score 1):

The supply is isolated, that means that you can have a reference of whatever you want (within reason)

Here is the standard configuration for generating pos and neg suppies

[image]

You can also connect the V- and parrallel the supplies.

[image]

Or do this:

[image]